# Problem with tracing a marker in an image

Tags: image-processing, correlation

My problem seems simple: I try to follow a marker across a number of images. All work fine, but when I update the marker from image to image, I observe a weird oscillatory behavior. I isolated the problem and it appears also in the case below, where I try to find the marker several times in the same image.

[image: enter image here]

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEVL0.jpg"];
size = 40 (*marker size*)
row = 256 (*marker center row*)
col = 1013(*marker center column*)
Do[
 {
  rowMin = row - size,
  rowMax = row + size,
  colMin = col - size,
  colMax = col + size,
  marker = ImageTake[image, {rowMin, rowMax}, {colMin, colMax}],(*marker images*)
  corr = ImageCorrelate[image, marker, SquaredEuclideanDistance], (*correlate image and marker*)
  min = PixelValuePositions[corr, "Min"] // First ,  
  Print[min],
  row = min[[2]],
  col = min[[1]],
  Print[marker]
 }, {i, 1, 5}]
```

I would expect to see the marker image five times. Instead it appears every second time and in between another section of the image appears.
Any thought why this is happens, and what I can do against it, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the marker image changes is because of the different coordinate origins used by [`ImageTake`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTake.html) and [`PixelValuePositions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PixelValuePositions.html). A quick fix is to add `ImageDimensions` after `Import`, and change `row = min[[2]]` to adjust for the different origins.

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[image]; (*needed to adjust image origin*)
```

The origin problem is easily fixed by changing this line in the `Do` statement:

```
row = min[[2]],
```

to:

```
row = h - min[[2]] + 1,
```

**Image origins used by ImageTake and PixelValuePositions**

The origin used by `ImageTake` is the *upper left* corner. Increasing row values count the vertical position from top to bottom, and increasing columns count the horizontal position from left to right.

[image: ImageTake from documentation]

The values returned by `PixelValuePositions` use an origin at the *lower left* corner. Increasing $x$ values count the horizontal position from left to right, and increasing $y$ values count the vertical position from bottom to top, offset by 0.5.

[image: PixelValuePositions from documentation]

When you use `PixelValuePositions` $x$ and $y$ values (lower left origin) with `ImageTake` (upper left origin), you need to adjust the vertical row-value for `ImageTake`.

Comment: thanks a lot for this piece of information. Work great now!!

Comment: @Christian - You're welcome. Please [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to show that it solved your problem.